# Find Column Data type in linked server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, linked-server

I just started working on a new project where data is stored in linked server. I have to add new columns to a table in staging environment, which already exists under same table name in linked server.

I have dumped data into a temp table but all the columns with data type decimals, int and numerics are converted into float in staging database. Also, when I'm trying to access information_schema or sys.columns for metadata getting below error. Any workaround to see the data type of table columns in linked server ?

```
select * from openquery(LINKEDSERVER,'select * from information_schema.columns')
```

Error:

```
OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKEDSERVER" returned message "[LINKEDSERVER][ODBC 64bit driver][OpenAccess SDK SQL Engine]Base table:columns not found.[10129]".
Msg 7321, Level 16, State 2, Line 45
An error occurred while preparing the query "select * from information_schema.columns" for execution against OLE DB provider "MSDASQL" for linked server "LINKEDSERVER".
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The best solution is to directly connect to the linked server and query its table definitions. What you are currently asking is akin to asking a mechanic how to take apart the engine through an exhaust pipe. If you want to go the hard way about it, you can use [`sp_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Well, I have limited access right now and I need to create the tables with the limited information I have. I tried the sp_describe_first_result_set already, even it shows all numeric columns as float in the result set.

Comment: **Then this is how they come to SQL server.** Is your linked server a SQL Server database or something else?

Comment: If SQL Server, ensure that you have configured your linked server connection to use Native SQL Server drivers.

Comment: Something does not look right. Why are you using this strange provider and what dbms engine are you linking to? It sounds like your linked server is an sql server instance but the "OpenAccess SDK ..." driver name suggests something very different.

Answer (score 4):

If you can query the linked server, then the following would work:

```
select
*
from    [LinkedServerInstanceHere].[DatabaseOnLinkedServerHere].information_schema.columns
```

Just populate your details in [ ]...

I just tested it and it works on my side.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you this is perfect.